# joining 2 text file and make a new file in python

Tags: pandas, file

I have 2 text files like the file1 and file2.

file1:

```
sample  group
s1      A
s2      B
s3      A
s4      B
```

file2:

```
ID      s1      s2      s3      s4
ag      5       6       65      74
ah      7       2       63      54
ay      8       7       4       15
ak      3       9       14      24
```

I would like to make a new text file from 2 input text files in which there would be 4 columns. the common information between 2 input files
is samples (in file1 is a column and in file2 samples are the headers of some columns including s1, s2, s3 and s4).
in the output file I want to transpose all the columns from file2 (except 1st column) so every item in the 1st column is repeated 4 times (since there are 4 samples). so the 1st column would be 4 repeat of IDs, the 2nd and 3rd columns would be transposed form and the last column would be the groups of every sample

expected output:

```
ID      sample  Value   group
ag      s1      5       A
ag      s2      6       B
ag      s3      65      A
ag      s4      74      B
ah      s1      7       A
ah      s2      2       B
ah      s3      63      A
ah      s4      54      B
ay      s1      8       A
ay      s2      7       B
ay      s3      4       A
ay      s4      15      B
ak      s1      3       A
ak      s2      9       B
ak      s3      14      A
ak      s4      24      B
```

to make such output I wrote the following code in python but it does not return the expected output. do you know how to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("infile1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("infile2.csv")
df3 = t(df2[, 2:])
result = pd.concat(df3, df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First we [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the columns of `df2` to index and then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the groups from `df1`. Finally we [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns as needed.

```
df3 = df2.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index().join(df1.set_index('sample'), on='level_1').rename(columns={'level_1': 'sample', 0: 'Value'})
```

Result:

```
    ID sample  Value group
0   ag     s1      5     A
1   ag     s2      6     B
2   ag     s3     65     A
3   ag     s4     74     B
4   ah     s1      7     A
5   ah     s2      2     B
6   ah     s3     63     A
7   ah     s4     54     B
8   ay     s1      8     A
9   ay     s2      7     B
10  ay     s3      4     A
11  ay     s4     15     B
12  ak     s1      3     A
13  ak     s2      9     B
14  ak     s3     14     A
15  ak     s4     24     B
```